# inject spring bean in a class not instantiated by spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a class called FileReader which I explicitly instantiate each time a new file gets generated. I would like to have a centrally managed singleton ExecutorService which gets inserted into FileReader each time I instantiate it. This executorservice is a singleton managed by Spring. I was wondering if it is possible to inject it (using autowiring or something like that)  in each new instance of FileReader as I create it explicitly (using something like FileReader fr = new FileReader() )

Comment: Why don't you create it using `new FileReader(executorService)`? As simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

You can check about [dependency injection of domain objects with Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable), the approach would be the same. You would need to enable load-time weaving for your project, though.

If you are not planning on doing this kind of thing very often, I suggest:

- manual injection, as @JB Nizet commented above, or
- define FileReader as a *prototype* bean, and change your `new FileReader()` occurrences to `applicationContext.getBean("fileReader")` or equivalent. Then you can inject whatever you want into `FileReader` via "plain" Spring. Personally I would encapsulate that `getBean()` invocation inside a `FileReaderFactory`, to avoid hard dependencies to Spring in my business classes.